# Nginx: pair nginx-balancer

Tags: linux, nginx, load-balancing, keep-alive

At the moment there is a nginx-balancer (Centos 7, a virtual machine with a white address) proxying to a large number of backend Apache servers. It is necessary to implement a failover cluster of two balancers on nginx. Fault tolerance is trially implemented using a virtual ip address (keepalived is used). Tell me what you can read about the pair nginx-balancer or how it can be implemented: all requests coming to them on the same virtual ip-address are evenly distributed between the two of them, but if one of them fails, the remaining one takes everything on itself?

At the moment, it turns out that there are two identical balancers and the benefit of the second is only in insurance. In the moments of full work of the main (master), the second (backup) is uselessly idle.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is active-active HA.. you can find something on google for nginx+ but by briefly looking at it I don't really see it as true active/active = there is not just one virtual (floating) IP.. instead active/active is achieved by using two floating IPs (two VRRP groups - one VIP address active on each nginx) and then using round-robin DNS A record containing both addresses.

As far as I know keepalived is using VRRP protocol which in some implementations can provide 'true' active/active.. anyway I'm not sure keepalived supports this. Based on informatin I'm able to lookup it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In several places, I read that the only implementation option is the round-robin DNS. But I would like to find other options. Maybe using HAProxy or Keepalived or some other way.